# DataAnnotations for jquery validation - Display error from one field on another field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

If I have a class like this:

```
class Sausage
{
    [Required]
    public string Location {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public decimal Lat {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public decimal Lng {get;set;}
}
```

If `Sausage.Lat` or `Sausage.Lng` is not filled out, I would like to populate an error message onto `Sausage.Location` instead... Is there an easy way of doing this?

The code might look like this:

```
class Sausage
{
    [Required]
    public string Location {get;set;}

    [Required]        
    [ErrorFor(Location, "The Location must be filled out")]
    public decimal Lat {get;set;}

    [Required]
    [ErrorFor(Location, "The Location must be filled out")]
    public decimal Lng {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the [IValidatableObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.validate(v=vs.100).aspx) interface previously to help with this.

There are other ways like creating custom validation attributes but I find this more easy for me:

```
public class Sausage : IValidatableObject
{

    public string Location { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Lat { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Lng { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Lat == decimal.Zero || Lng == decimal.Zero)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Please ensure both Lng & Lat is filled in", new[] { "Location" });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortuantely when Lat and Lng are empty, the error does not come up for jquery validation and yet the jquery validation is failing because they are not filled in, so the user cannot save the form.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my answer, how can Lat and Lng be empty? They are both set as decimals and not nullable decimals. Perhaps post the code for your html view. If you want to use custom jquery validation have a look at: http://blog.andrei.rinea.ro/2013/06/28/building-client-javascript-custom-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-4-using-jquery/.

Comment: It's really for the jquery validation side... so while in html... the values can actually be null... When they are posted through to the controller they are then settled as 0... I need the jquery validation part in ASP new MVC to understand that if they are in fact null... it should show the error on the location field. - Client side validation

Comment: This isn't a problem in the C# domain, purely the JavaScript domain then, if you want the errors to come from the server side, then you should think about posting meta data to the form as well.